# Is it possible to detect the absence of related events based on given timout using azure stream analytics?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Say you have events telling you when given doors in a building are opened and closed and how long each door is allowed to remained opened before an alarm is triggered.

Something like: (might need a timestamp too on events...)
{ "id": 1, "event":"Opened", "toBeClosedInSeconds":30 }
{ "id": 1, "event": "Closed" }

Is it possible to use Azure stream analytics to identify doors left open for more than the given timeframe? That is, identify the absence of closed before the given timeout passes? And if so, what would such a query look like?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** It’s difficult for the stream processing system to know if there are no events, or if events are delayed.

In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-time-handling), we discuss how you can make design choices to solve practical time handling problems in the Azure Stream Analytics service. Time handling design decisions are closely related to event ordering factors.

Hope this helps.